# Size Alignment in Dreamweaver cc bootstrap for Thumbnails

Tags: css, dreamweaver

Hi briefly I am kinda new to this.
I am using Dreamweaver CC 2017.
I would like to make my thumbnails look the same size.
Here is my website link http://www.hisseforex.com/index.html
Right below you can see the thumbnails. I want them to be aligned and same size regardless of how big is my text there. 
This is my first question here so apologies in advance if I couldnt put the question right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position absolute of `.thumbnail img`, remove it.
Remove all styles from

```
.thumbnail img {    
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I removed all styles I put before to fix it. But it is vetically not aligned still.

Comment: Add a **margin-top:10px** to **.thumbnail img**

Comment: http://www.hisseforex.com/   looks like this still. The bottom lines still not matching. I use same size pics.I guess I have to fix thumbnail size to row sizesomehow but dont know how to do that. I tried a lot of things

Comment: Two options. Set a static height to **.thumbnail** or use a jQuery pluging to equal heights.